# Why did North Korea, the last country with nukes, self-destruct its nukes?

Tags: plot-explanation, gi-joe-retaliation

[This clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eaB49GtSazQ) from *G.I. Joe: Retaliation* shows North Korea as the last country with nuclear weapons in the air. It's clearly established, and to my knowledge a key plot point, that at this point of time everyone else has no nukes. Despite this, North Korea decides to self-destruct its nukes mere minutes away from absolute victory over their American enemies. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from being an absolutely absurd premise, North Korea at that point doesn't have any nukes in their reserve because they just launched them all. They also don't have enough to destroy *every* nation. If they let their nukes land then they will have a target on their back with absolutely no nuclear deterrence.

The clip also seems to suggest that the current leader of North Korea is somewhat sane who cares about his reputation in world history just like all the other world leaders in that room. He doesn't want to go down as the madman that just randomly launched hundreds of nuclear warheads. He wants to stay in power of his nation; not destroy other nations.